# Prevent items in a library within app/add-in appearing in the SharePoint Online Search Results while still being able search it via CSOM or REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-addin

I am developing a Add-In for Sharepoint. The App-web for the add-in contains a document library where I store some data.

I want to stop the items in this document library appearing in the results of the share point search when a user is searching from the host web. However I still want to be able to search the contents of the document library programmatically.

*What I have tried*

I tried turning off the "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?" option in the settings of the document library (Document Library>>Settings>Advance>>), however when I did that, I couldn’t even search the library programmatically.

**Does anyone know a way to hide the items from Sharepoint search results in the host web while being able to get results programmatically?**

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried this, but perhaps editing the default result sources to exclude items from the app's web.

Comment: My Add-In only request app only permission from the tenant. so i wont have access to the edit the default results sources in the host web. is there a way around it?